# Objective-Cで定義されたメソッドのオーバーライドでエラー

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

Swift 2でObjective-Cのメソッドをオーバーライドしていたのですが、Swift 3にしたところ以下のエラーが出るようになりました。どのようにしたらエラーが解消されるかお知恵を貸していただけないでしょうか？

**Method does not override any method from its superclass**

以下がObjective-Cのメソッドになります。

```
- (void)loadContentsInPage:(NSInteger)page handler:(void (^)(BOOL hasNext, NSError *error))handler;
```

それをSwift 2ではこのようにオーバーライドしていて、Swift 3にしたところ上記のエラーが出ています。

```
override func loadContents(inPage page: Int, handler: ((Bool, NSError?) -> Void)!) {
    // コード
}
```

以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 3では以下のようなメソッドシグネチャになります（`NSError` => `Error`）。

```
override func loadContents(inPage page: Int, handler: ((Bool, Error?) -> Void)!) {

}
```

コツとしてメソッドのオーバーライドはXcodeの補完機能を利用して記述すると確実です。

今回の例でしたらオーバーライドしたいクラスの中で下記のように`func`や`override`を打たずにいきなり`loadc`くらいまで打つと補完が表示されるので候補から選択すると、上記のシグネチャがすべて入力されます。関数名をいきなりタイプするのがポイントです。

```
class Controller: ViewController {
    loadc
}
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
おかげさまで無事解決しました。
こういうところで基礎がしっかりしていないことが露呈しますね。

P.S.
開発中のアプリでRealmやKeychainAccessを使わさせていただいています。ありがとうございます^^